# AWS X-Ray with Node.JS Express and request

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, request, aws-xray

So I'm trying to implement X-Ray with my express app.
I have my app.js file and inside reference a router file.

my project structure:
`project/
  routes/
    index.js
  app.js`

app.js:

```
var indexRouter = require("./routes/index")
...
app.use("/", indexRouter)
...
```

index.js:

```
const AWSXRay = require("aws-xray-sdk")
const request = require("request")

router.post("/xray", async function(req, res, next) {
    let app = req.app
    app.use(AWSXRay.express.openSegment("MyApp"))

    try {
        console.log(AWSXRay.getSegment()) // this succesfully gets segment
        AWSXRay.captureAsyncFunc("send", function(subsegment) {
            request.get("http://www.google.com", { XRaySegment: subsegment }, function() {
                res.json({
                    success: "success"
                })
                subsegment.close()
        })
    } catch (err) {
        next(err)
    }
    app.use(AWSXRay.express.closeSegment())
})
```

I'm following the automatic mode examples: Capture through async function calls from the AWS documentation (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray-sdk-for-nodejs/latest/reference/index.html), but I am getting a error that says:
"Failed to get the current sub/segment from the context."

Can anyone let me know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move the `app.use(AWSXRay.express.openSegment("MyApp"))` code to the `app.js` above the `app.use("/", indexRouter)`

Then move the `app.use(AWSXRay.express.closeSegment())` below the `app.use("/", indexRouter)`.

If you look at the code referenced in the link provided, you'll notice the `openSegment` and `closeSegment` are outside the route, not inside (as you have them currently)

Code in link for reference:

```
var app = express();

//...

var AWSXRay = require('aws-xray-sdk');

app.use(AWSXRay.express.openSegment('defaultName'));               //required at the start of your routes

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index');
});

app.use(AWSXRay.express.closeSegment());   //Required at the end of your routes / first in error handling routes
```